# QGIS WCS client with clip parameter

Tags: qgis, wcs

Can be defined bbox parameter in a WCS service? I require trimming the layer coordinate in a box, I'm trying to prove the following WCS, but shows the entire layer globally:

http://geobrain.laits.gmu.edu/cgi-bin/gbwcs-dem?bbox=-76.70429,7.26988,-74.59818,9.56054&crs=epsg:4326

regards,

Samuel Mesa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say in your question what version of WCS is the highest supported by the service.

If for example the WCS service supports version 2.0.0 (or higher) then a BBOX request like this will not work (if you don't specify the version in the request you get the highest version supported). Instead you will need to using a trim sub-setting operation.  The request would look something like:

```
http://[your-service]?service=WCS&request=GetCoverage&CoverageId=[your-id]&subset=x(76.70429,-74.59818)&subset=y(7.26988,9.56054)&
```