# Using GeoBrain WCS4DEM in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, wcs, geobrain

I added the GeoBrain WCS server to the server list:
http://geobrain.laits.gmu.edu/cgi-bin/gbwcs-dem?version=1.0.0&

I connect to the server and get a list of layers. I select the first one listed - SRTM 30MUSA and select ADD. My map window is displaying a region in NM, the project CRS is EPSG:4326. The response is

[image: as here]

Note that the bbox is nonsense.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95247/qgis-wcs-client-with-clip-parameter?rq=1) is closely related, asking how to use a clip region to set the bbox in a WCS request, and the example is also GeoBrain.